# How to record a specific area of the screen with QuickTime Player

Tags: quicktime, recording

I've tried to record a specific part of the screen with QuickTime Player. But again nothing works as expected with the Mac, but I have to work with.

My result is always a black video with the selected size.

What I've done so far:

- Open: QuickTime Player
- Choose: File > New Recording Screen
- Press: Red Button
- Mark an area on the screen for which I want to record.
- Click: Start Recording

On the screen recording I press stop and I get back to the player.
When I play the recorded movie, I only get a blank screen. I see from the consumed time, that it was recorded and also a save would be not empty.

What is the trick to getting something useful with this Apple Product?

Comment: What are you trying to record? Is it some kind of movie (It might restrict the ability to record it from QuickTime)? Please try to record for example TextEdit app.

Comment: I record my own app and I don't think that quicktime technically can indicate if I am recording a movie or a simple gui. Also recording a very small part of the GUI is not possible. I know for recording an app I could record directly from the device, but then quicktime crashes after some seconds. Very disappointing the MAC in general.

Comment: FYI Quicktime will not record a DVD on screen, nor DRM protected web content